# How can i transfer value which has been typed in <input number> object into javascript without page refreshing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem with transferring value from the  object to the javascript without page refresh. I have noticed, that if my page refresh, my value disappear.

```
Fiddle example:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcgy3/185/

Could someone help me with this problem ? Thank You in advance :)

Comment: add a default value to your input `<input  type="number" id="num_of_balls" min="1" max="20" value='1'>`

Comment: Do you want to submit information to the server with the form or are you just building a front end for calculations?

Comment: @BipBip Thank you for Your answer, but it's not what i want to achieve. I want to transfer my value, which i type in input object, to my javascript code after i click enter button.

Comment: @Neil Munro 
I want to transfer value to code on the same page. I am not using server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't technically need the form, you could just have the elements on their own. Does this answer the question you have?

HTML:

```
Value(between 1 and 20):
<input  type="number" id="num_of_balls" min="1" max="20">
<button id="clickBTN">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
function onClick() {
  var ballCount = parseInt(document.getElementById("num_of_balls").value, 10);
  if(ballCount < 1 || ballCount > 20) return; // it have to be value between 1 and 20 to continue 
  var i = 0;

  alert("#Balls: " + ballCount);
  for (i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {
    obj_t.push({
      xPos : 10 + 10 * i,
      yPos : 10 + 11 * i,
      xVel : 0 + i / 10,
      yVel : 1 + i / 10,
      r : 2 + i / 5
    });
  }
}

var obj_t = [];
var btn = document.getElementById("clickBTN");
btn.addEventListener("click", onClick);
document.getElementById("num_of_balls").addEventListener("keypress", (evt) => {
  if(evt.key === "Enter") {
    onClick();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank You for the answear, You are a bit closer to right answear. There is two problems anyway. First: You can transer values which are greater than 20. Second one is that I can't accept the value by pressing enter on my keyboard.
Fiddle example: 

http://jsfiddle.net/pcgy3/190/

Comment: I've added an event listener for the enter key. Worked in Firefox 44.

Comment: Thank You! Is is working, but it allow transfering value greater than 20 anyway :/ http://jsfiddle.net/pcgy3/191/

Comment: I've added a quick check for being between 0-20 and returning as early as possible if the data is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can a listener to the input change :

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    obj_t=[];
    for (var i = 0; i <   document.getElementById('num_of_balls').value; i++) {
        var obj = {
            xPos : 10 + 10 * i,
            yPos : 10 + 11 * i,
            xVel : 0 + i / 10,
            yVel : 1 + i / 10,
            r : 2 + i / 5
        }
        obj_t.push(obj);
    }

  console.log(obj_t);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcgy3/188/

Comment: Thank You for the anser, but I don't want to transfer value after button pressing, but after i click enter.

Answer (score 0):

That is obvious, none of the changed made to the DOM stays once after the page gets reloaded, unless you are storing the the value somewhere in cookie, session, local-storage or DB.

Though here is an example of getting the value in JS.
Iam using JQuery .keyup as an event which will trigger the value from

**HTML:**

```
<input  type="number" id="num_of_balls" min="1" max="20">
```

**JS**

```
  $('#num_of_balls').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) { // on Enter key pressed
            alert(document.getElementById('num_of_balls').value)
        }
  })
```

Code here http://jsfiddle.net/pcgy3/189/

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but I don't want to transfer value after button pressing, but after i click enter. And in Your solution, You can type number greater than 20.